# What does a proportional matrix look like for glmnet response variable in R?

Tags: r, glmnet

I'm trying to use `glmnet` to fit a GLM that has a proportional response variable (using the `family="binomial"`).

The help file for `glmnet` says that the response variable:

"For family="binomial" should be either a factor with
two levels, or a two-column matrix of counts or proportions (the second column
is treated as the target class"

But I don't really understand how I would have a two column matrix. My variable is currently just a single column with values between 0 and 1. Can someone help me figure out how this needs to be formatted so that `glmnet` will run it properly? Also, can you explain what the target class means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matrix of positive label and negative label counts, for example in the example below we fit a model for proportion of `Claims` among `Holders` :

```
data = MASS::Insurance
y_counts = cbind(data$Holders - data$Claims,data$Claims)
x = model.matrix(~District+Age+Group,data=data)

fit1 = glmnet(x=x,y=y_counts,family="binomial",lambda=0.001)
```

If possible, so you should go back to before your calculation of the response variable and retrieve these counts. If that is not possible, you can provide a matrix of proportion, 2nd column for success but this assumes the weight or n is same for all observations:

```
y_prop = y_counts / rowSums(y_counts)
fit2 = glmnet(x=x,y=y_prop,family="binomial",lambda=0.001)
```